# jQuery: How to Auto Fit Google Maps with Address Array

Tags: jquery, maps

I have this code that pulls address from an array and tags them on a map.  How would I get the map to auto fit to the results?  In this example, it should auto fit to the United States (for the most part).

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2QhE/1149/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map;
    var elevator;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);  
    var addresses = ['TX', 'New York', 'California','Florida','MI'];

    for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
        $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode    /json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bounds` object and remember locations of added markers.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            var addresses = ['Norway', 'Africa', 'Asia','North America','South America'];
            var map;

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var elevator;
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);  
            var addresses = ['TX', 'New York', 'California','Florida','MI'];

            for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
                $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', {  }, function (data) {
                    var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
                    bounds.extend(latlng);
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map
                    });                        

                    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });
            }
        });
```